# Downgrade git on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

What is the best way to downgrade git into the 1.7.x series on a brand new Ubuntu 13.10 release?

I'm trying to find some ppa for this, but I'm not seeing any.

Comment: You could deinstall and compile from source but why do you want to downgrade in the first place?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and just reinstalling the version you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First install the `git` package from an Ubuntu release having Git 1.7 - say, 12.04 LTS (precise).  Either [download these manually](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all) and install them using `dpkg` (simpler option), or (if you'll also need lots of other packages from precise) add the precise package repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and install them using `apt-get`:

```
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t precise install git
```

Once that's successfully done, [pin or hold](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the git packages in `apt` to prevent them from being updated.  Pinning is the traditional solution (I've used this on Debian or Ubuntu for years) - see the linked howto for more info on this.  Holding is the newer approach and looks far simpler/easier:

```
sudo apt-mark hold git
```

Comment: For me it needed to be precise.list not precise so that apt didn't complain:
`echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list`

Also, fwiw, I needed to downgrade git because of an issue with pip, so the following worked for me:
`$sudo apt-get remove git git-man` & 
`echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raring.list` &
`sudo apt-get update` & 
`sudo apt-get -t raring install git-man git` & 
`sudo apt-mark hold git-man git`

Answer (score 4):

- Remove current version:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove git-core git-svn git-email
  ```
- Install libcurl3-dev, asciidoc, autoconf and xmlto:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev asciidoc xmlto autoconf
  ```
- Download the tarball and extract its content:

  ```
  tar -xvzf git_x.y.z.tgz
  ```
- Enter the git directory:

  ```
  cd git
  ```
- Compile and install:

  ```
   make configure
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
   make all doc
   sudo make install install-doc
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Running an old version is probably a bad idea but if you really want to do it, you'll have to install it from source.

Simply [download the source code for the version of your choice](https://github.com/git/git/releases), remove the existing git package with `apt-get remove git` and then manually compile git from source. You can check the [INSTALL file for full instructions](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) but basically, make sure that you've already got build-essential from apt-get and then `make; make install`